# React Packager doesn't detect all the time change file on Windows

Tags: react-native

I have some issues with React Packager on Windows

[Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSiPq.png)

After loading (long long wait), my application is lauching well on AVD Android. But when i change a file and i reload on my app, i see no change. I can do that 10X and no change. (I'm talking about the welcom react base app and i change index.android.js file so nothing very exotic)

Some times, the change on *.js file are detected and my app update well. When it work, it work all the time until i stop the packager. When it doesn't work, it doesn't working until i restart packager.

So for too work, i have to launch, try, launch, try, launch try until it is ok. As you can see, the loading can take 3min so it's not cool.

I tried to activate, desactivate hot reload but no change.

I don't think it's a network issue because after reboot packager, sometimes i have the old version. So i use --clear-cache option. And when i reload the app in android, i can see that packager catch the request but don't send the good version.

So i've conclued that Packager didn't detect very well the file change.

I know on Windows Watchman does not existe maybe there is a work around !!! If you have a solution for slow loading i'm ok too :-)

Can you help me ?

npm -v react-native : 2.15.1
npm -v : 2.15.1
node -v : v4.4.4

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with nodejs 4. But when I installed nodejs 6 and make run-android init again the problem is fixed. Try to uninstall node 4 and install node 6.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

After deleting .expo and node_modules folders and running `yarn install` changes detection started working again